# Proving That the Following Set is Countable

Tags: real-analysis

The Question:

Fixing $n$ to be an element of the natural numbers, let $A_n$ be the set of algebraic numbers obtained as roots of polynomials with integer coefficients that have degree $n$. Show that $A_n$ is countable.

My Thoughts:

-Using the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra I know that every polynomial has a finite number of roots.

Comment: You've got exactly the right idea.

Comment: Consider the set of polynomials where all coefficients are additionally bounded by some $k\in\mathbb N$, and then their union.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can biject the set of polynomials in question with $\mathbb{N}$.